# How to convert HTML table to angular material table (mat-table)?

Tags: html, angular, html-table, angular-material

I have new to Angular Material and trying to convert basic Angular table to Angular material table using
`mat-table`

I am not sure where to start from. How can I convert below table to mat-table?

Here is my .html file which contains table

```html
<div>
    <h2>Count Data</h2>

<ng-container>
    <table style = 'width: 50%;'>
        <tr>
            <td>Select 1 {{newFinal.color}}</td>
            <td>{{newFinal.zind}}</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td colspan = '3' class = 'bold'> Wasi Final: {{newFinal.Queue}} ({{newFinal.selection}}) </td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td colspan = '3' class = 'bold'> Collar Final: ({{newFinal.Titir}}) </td>
        </tr>
    

    </table>
 
</ng-container>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

the doc is amazing and full of example